# How can I make it so my field is only set the one time?

Tags: c#

I have a field in my model class that's coded as follows:

```
    public string CreatedBy
    {
        get { return _CreatedBy; }
        set { _CreatedBy = value; Created = DateTime.Now; }
    }
    public DateTime? Created { get; set; }
```

When the CreatedBy field is populated then it fills out the Created date automatically. The problem for me is that if I again set the CreatedBy field (yes it can happen) then the date gets updated with the current date again.

Is there a way that I can make it so the CreatedBy and the Created fields can be populated just once?

Comment: populated once by who? Is this being persisted in a DB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a backing field and check whether the value has been set already - if so, leave it unchanged:

```
private DateTime? created;
public DateTime? Created 
{
    get { return created; }
    set { if (created == null) created = value; }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Can't you check, within the set, whether there is already a value and simply not set the new value?

Answer (score 1):

Make use of constructor and iniailize the property to defult value you want

```
public classConstructor()
{
   propertyName = defaultValue;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a quick way: use the ?? operator. If Created is null, it will go to DateTime.Now.

```
public string CreatedBy
{
    get { return _CreatedBy; }
    set { _CreatedBy = value; Created = Created ?? DateTime.Now; }
}
public DateTime? Created { get; set; }
```

Comment: +1 Answers the question without telling the OP to set the value in the constructor (which may or may not be a good suggestion)

Comment: @KirkBroadhurst Well, having it set in the constructor was sure to come up as an answer. It would be *the* desired use case (set it once, forget about it), rather than having some property's set with a side effect of setting another property which, albeit often bad design, might be the desired effect here.

Comment: But you can't set every property in the constructor! Any property called 'Created...' does *sound* like it should be set in the constructor, but I never assume these sort of things.

Comment: @KirkBroadhurst Of course not, and that's not what I said. I'm just saying, setting a property which causes the setting of another property: awkward design, and dangerous.

Answer (score 1):

In that case it would probably be best to include `CreatedBy` in the constructor. This would imply "create-time" semantics:

```
public string CreatedBy
{
    get;
    private set;
}

public DateTime? Created
{
    get;
    private set;
}

public Model(..., string createdBy)
{
    this.CreatedBy = createdBy;
    this.Created = DateTime.Now;
}

// another option, if you don't like the ctor route
public void AssignCreator(string createdBy)
{
    if (this.Created.HasValue) throw new InvalidOperationException();
    this.CreatedBy = createdBy;
    this.Created = DateTime.Now;
}
```

Your other option would be to throw an `InvalidOperationException` in the property setter if `Created` is non-null.